# file_get_contents suddenly returns false

Tags: php

a fews days ago my little php script suddenly stopped working. Before that I never had issues with exactly that code.

But now `file_get_contens` suddenly retuns false. Even though the url does return a proper json file, if I do open it directly through the browser. `allow_url_fopen` is active. And other urls still work.

```
  $path = "https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?where=GEN%20%3D%20%27LEVERKUSEN%27&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json&".date("Ymdhis");
  $datafile = file_get_contents($path);
  var_dump($datafile);
```

Do have any idea, what suddenly went wrong?

Comment: Check your web servers error log to see if you have any errors. You can also check with the owner of that URL. Maybe the server has been blocked?

Comment: You can also check the magic variable [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) after the call to see if there's any clues in the response headers. Just add `var_dump($http_response_header);` after the call. There's not really much we can help with if one of the calls to an external server suddenly stops working, without knowing why.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The response header shows an "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" error from cloudfront. So it is not my fault, right?

Comment: No, that means that you're blocked for some reason. How often do you make these calls? Either way, you need to contact the API owners.